# javascript - resize all images on click

Tags: javascript, resize, image

I am creating an image gallery of sorts and I want users to have a choice between small, medium, and large thumbnails and have it change without reloading the page. What would the Jaavascript be so that on a mouseclick of a button, all the images with a certain class get resized dynamically?

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS?  This will help determine how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set up classes for your different sizes.

```
$('input#small').click( function()
{
    $('img').removeClass('large medium').addClass('small');
}

$('input#medium').click( function()
{
    $('img').removeClass('large small').addClass('medium');
}

$('input#large').click( function()
{
    $('img').removeClass('medium small').addClass('large');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allImgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    allImgsLength = allImgs.length,
    className = 'something';


for (var i = 0, i < allImgsLength; i++) {
   var image = allImgs[i];

   if (image.className.match(new RegExp('\b' + className + '\b')) {
       // Set what sizes you need
       image.style.width = '400px';
       image.style.height = '200px';

   }

}
```

Comment: Whoa, now that's pretty insane for some reason. I just don't know why (maybe because I've gotten so used to jQuery, I forgot that JS can actually do this quite easily)...

Comment: @Blender Unfortunately, I wouldn't say the above is easy. I'd rather be able to get elements with a classname without having to deal with regex. Some browsers support `getElementsByClassName` natively :)

Comment: I wonder which ones don't ;) With future JS developments (like that pretty cool function) and implementations, jQuery might be pretty easy to replace with library-less JS.

Comment: @Blender [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) is like a native [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) :P

Comment: I've seen that jQuery includes Sizzle into it's source, so maybe I should check out Sizzle, as it seems to be a lot lighter than jQuery. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Blender Sizzle is just the selector engine for jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$('input#foobar').click(function()
{
  var newHeight = 200;

  $('img.foo').each(function()
  {
    if ($(this).height() > 200)
    {
      $(this).css('height', parseInt(newHeight * $(this).css('width') / $(this).css('height')) + 'px');
    }
  });
});
```

No guarantees that this will work perfectly, but you can at least build off of it to add different size increments, etc.